# Smooth animation using jarallax and jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have jarallax working well with my web page. Problem is the images animate really bad(pixels per scroll).

I've tried to implement this code

```
 <script>
    $('#Wrapper').bind('mousewheel', function (e) {
        if (!(e.originalEvent.wheelDelta == 120)) {
            var top = parseInt($("#child").css("top"));
            $("#child").css("top", (top - 100) + "px");
            top = parseInt($("#child").css("top"));
            if (top <= -500) {
                setTimeout(function () {
                    $("#child").css("top", "-500px");
                }, 100);
            }
        } else {
            var top = parseInt($("#child").css("top"));

            $("#child").css("top", (top + 100) + "px");
            top = parseInt($("#child").css("top"));
            if (top >= 0) {
                setTimeout(function () {
                    $("#child").css("top", "0");
                }, 100);               
            }            
         }        
   });

</script>
```

and html

```
<body onload="init()">
<div id="Wrapper">
    <div id="child">
<--!> Content </-->
```

Problem is, its not animating with scrolls. This is a single page website.

I've also tried a few jquery mouse plugins and im not seeming to get this right. any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try using the event 'scroll' instead of 'mousewheel'.

Comment: tried the scroll instead of mousewheel and nothing.

Comment: Check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2fUr6/3/ the CSS properties are applied correctly.